# Preciso atualizar meu banco de dados acces(.mdb), de um computador externo

Tags: banco-de-dados, visual-basic-6, microsoft-access

Ola, tenho um cliente com duas lojas e preciso que o banco de dados seja interlidado. Preciso de um norte sobre como começar a estudar isso.

obs: o banco de dados é local, não esta na nuvem

Comment: Acredito que uma saída para isso é ter um terceiro banco na nuvem e os pdv trocarem informações por esse banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola,

Eu fiz um Sistema em Access com VBA que utilizei o Banco de Dados Mysql.
No caso meu provedor de E-mail ( Localweb ) disponibiliza o Banco de Dados gratuitamente. E criei vários Bancos e utilizei o PHPMYADMIN para manipular tudo.
Se voce tiver um conhecimento Basico em SQL ( Select, Update e Insert ) já conseguira fazer muitas coisas. Existem muitos vídeos para auxiliar com o Mysql até por que as instruções são fáceis de fazer.
Com o Mysql voce precisará usar o ADO ou o DAO Vba.
Eu gosto do ADO.
Abaixo vou colocar link de um Video do Guru do Excel.
Ele explica como conectar um Formulario Excel com o Access.
Voce pode usar todas as formas de conexão que ele explica somente mudando para o Mysql.

https://youtu.be/cI7rzXSRUb8

Obs.: para conectar com o Mysql voce precisará ter na maquina o Drive do Oldb. Eu uso a versão 5.3. Caso queira, eu te passo uma conexão minha do Access com o Mysql.

Espero ter ajudado